# Instantiate class by reference

Tags: python

I would like to create a dictionary which based on a string keyword returns a subclass of Foo which I can later instantiate. Is this possible or is it an incorrect approach to the problem?

Pseudo code:

```
subclasses_of_foo = {"foo1": Foo1, "foo2": Foo2}
subclass_of_foo = subclasses_of_foo["foo1"]

instance = subclass_of_foo()
```

Comment: Not what "duck typing" means but yeah that works.

Comment: You can even do `instance = subclasses_of_foo["foo1"]()` if you like

Comment: It's duck typing if you drop the subclass part right? (as long as I intend to call a method on the instantiated object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can do that.  Give it a go.

Comment: Thank you! I had just messed up the order of the class map and class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is entirely correct and works. Classes are *just objects*, just like everything else in Python. They can be stored as values in a dictionary.

Demo:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     pass
... 
>>> class Bar:
...     pass
... 
>>> classmap = {'foo': Foo, 'bar': Bar}
>>> classmap['foo']
<class __main__.Foo at 0x107eee1f0>
>>> classmap['foo']()
<__main__.Foo instance at 0x107eefcb0>
```

Note that [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is something else entirely; it is the practice of treating any object as the correct type provided it implements the attributes and methods you expected (*if it walks like a duck, it **is** a duck*).

Comment: Thank you! I had just messed up the order of the class map and class definition.